# How to convert list of dicts to dicts?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a list of dict that I am struggling to change to list of dicts:

```
x = [
    { # begin first and only dict in list
        '11': [{'bb': '224', 'cc': '14'}, {'bb': '254', 'cc': '16'}]
        , '22': [{'bb': '824', 'cc': '19'}]
    }
]
```

Which currently has a length of 1.  i.e.:

```
print(len(x)) # 1
```

I intend to change it to list of dicts. i.e.:

```
desired = [
    { # begin first dict in list
        '11': [{'bb': '224', 'cc': '14'}, {'bb': '254', 'cc': '16'}]
    }
    , { # begin second dict in list
        '22': [{'bb': '824', 'cc': '19'}]
    }
]
    
print(len(desired)) # 2
```

What I tried:

```
dd = {}
for elem in x:
    for k,v in elem.items():
        dd[k] = v
print([dd])

print(len(dd)) # 2
```

Is there a better way or perhaps more efficient way?

Comment: @Sphinx i just edited my wuestion

Comment: I think your approach is good enough. because one nested loop is required based on current scenario you provided. I already voted to reopen this question, probably someone else has better idea.

Answer (score 2):

Like others mentioned, there is nothing "wrong" with what you've tried. However, you might be interested in trying a list comprehension:

```
x_desired = [{k: v} for i in x for k, v in i.items()]
```

Like your attempted approach, this is effectively 2 for loops, the second nested within the first. In general, list comprehensions are considered fast and Pythonic.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the result to be `2` as you"ve got two keys (`11` & `22`) ?
then try this:

```
print(len(x[0]))
```